# What is the Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space of $k(x,y)=\langle x,y\rangle^2$?

Tags: kernel-trick, mathematical-statistics

Digging in the definition of Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces (RKHS) I came across the following example taken from pages 49-51 of [1]:

Given the kernel $k(x,y) = \langle x,y\rangle^2$, with $x,y\in \mathbb R^2$, one can show that both

$\phi(x) = [x_1^2,~ x_2^2,~ x_1x_2, ~x_1x_2]$, with feature space $\mathcal H = \mathbb R^4$

$\phi^{\prime}(x) = [x_1^2,~ x_2^2,~ \sqrt 2 x_1x_2]$, with feature space $\mathcal H^\prime = \mathbb R^3$

are valid feature maps for the kernel. However, the slides point  out that neither $\mathcal H$ nor $\mathcal H^\prime$ are RKHS because the RKHS must by definition be unique for a given kernel. **Can you explain what the RKHS would be in this case?**

Other references on the topic state that the RKHS $\mathcal H_k$ is *unique up to isomorphism* [2]. Under this definition I guess both  $\mathcal H$ and $\mathcal H^\prime$ can be considered RKHS by being isomorphic to  $\mathcal H_k$.

[1] http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~sejdinov/teaching/atml14/Theory_slides1_2014.pdf

[2] http://users.umiacs.umd.edu/~hal/docs/daume04rkhs.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prof. Dino Sejdinovic, author of the slides my question referred to, was kind enough to send me the following answer:

> Feature spaces are not unique and indeed they are all isomorphic. RKHS
>   of a given kernel is unique as *a space of functions*, i.e. the one
>   that contains functions of the form $k(\cdot , x)$. If these functions form a
>   finite-dimensional RKHS, that RKHS is isomorphic to a standard
>   Euclidean space of that dimension. For intuition about uniqueness for
>   infinite-dimensional case, you can consider an orthonormal basis of
>   $\mathcal H_k$, e.g. given by Mercer's theorem -- then the $\ell^2$ space of
>   coefficients corresponding to this basis is a valid feature space and
>   isomorphic to RKHS. You can choose many different bases so there are
>   many versions of feature spaces. But they all correspond to the same
>   space of functions which is the RKHS.

In addition, the first twenty minutes of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XsJxCMnLm4) class by Prof. Lorenzo Rosasco delve a bit deeper into the relation between feature spaces, feature maps and RKHS.

Comment: What did he mean by "If these functions form a finite-dimensional RKHS, that RKHS is isomorphic to a standard Euclidean space of that dimension" ?